# Not able to override fonts in different views when I set a font in the app theme

Tags: android, fonts, material-components-android

I set a font in my app theme, like `font1`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/font1</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Then when I try to set another font to one of my `TextView`s like `font2`:

```
<TextView
...
android:fontFamily="@font/font2"/>
```

my expectation is that I'd see the `font2` style in the screen for this TextView, but it doesn't take effect and still shows `font1` style.

So my question is, why isn't `font2` applied to the `TextView` and it's still showing `font1`?

**Note:** I'm using MaterialComponenets theme, not AppCompat them

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
app:fontFamily="@font/font2"
```